# Who is the block builder and how to be one?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I read the documentation about Ether PoS, and 32 ETH is required if anyone wants to become a Valiator and proposer, but it's not quite clear what exactly is the role of a **block builder**, can anyone explain it to me please, and also what should I do if I want to become a builder?
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The term "block builder" is not a separate role from being a validator and proposer.  When you become a validator, you automatically take on the responsibilities of proposing blocks as well. In another words, "block builder" is simply another term for a validator who proposes blocks in Ethereum's PoS system. So, as a validator in Ethereum's PoS, your role includes:Proposing Blocks, Validating Blocks.

And if you wanna be a builder, you need to 1. Stake 32 ETH. 2. Set up a validator node.
3. Participate in block proposal and validation as part of the PoS consensus.

Hope this will help you in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Block building is a new role introduced by proposer-builder separation (PBS). Block builders are highly specialized actors who construct blocks from transaction orderflow (public transactions, bundles, private transactions, etc). Builders run algorithms and simulations (e.g. First Come First Serve, First Price Auctions, etc.) to order bundles and TXs in a block template (technically: `execution payload`) that maximizes profit. Builders then bid for and buy the validators’ blockspace, facilitated by one or more relays, so their execution payloads are proposed to the blockchain.

References

- https://ethereum.org/nl/roadmap/pbs
- https://boost.flashbots.net/
- https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-mev-boost/block-builders

Answer (score 1):

To become a block validator or block proposer, You need to stake 32 ETH as the collateral. By becoming a block validator you verify the transactions and include them in your block and propose it. All you need is a basic hardware for running the node and 32 ETH. For running this you get mining rewards.